# Issue with error validation and page action?

Tags: php, forms, validation

Hi guys I'm new to coding and loving every minute of it :)
So the following code is in my registration.php file.  I want to make it so that when the user fills everything BEFORE it will direct them to my invoice.php file after pressing the register button.  If they are missing some requirements, go back to the registration form and (hopefully after I get this figured out, put some sticky forms so they don't have to type in whatever text was validated)  Also, getting an **error "
Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_2\registration.php** on line 9" on my validation at the top of my PHP code, not too sure what I'm suppose to put there. :( As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    <html>
    <h4>
        <center>
            New User Registration
        </center>
    </h4>
    <body>
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]=="login")
    {
        if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}$/", $_POST["user"]) === 0)
          $errUser = '<p class="errText">User must be bigger that 5 chars and contain only digits, letters and underscore</p>';
        // Password must be strong
        //if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["pass"]) === 0)
        if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["pass"]) === 0)
          $errPass = '<p class="errText">Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit</p>';
    // Email mask
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", $_POST["email"]) === 0)
          $errEmail = '<p class="errText">Email must comply with this mask: chars(.chars)@chars(.chars).chars(2-4)</p>';


    }    




  ?>
        <form action="invoice.php" method="post">
            <center>
                <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td <input name="user" type="text" size="16" value="<?php echo $_POST["user"]; ?>">
          <?php  if(isset($errUser)) echo $errUser; ?>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="pass" type="password" size="16" value="<?php echo $_POST["pass"]; ?>">
          <?php  if(isset($errPass)) echo $errPass; ?>
                    </tr>
                                         <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="email" type="text" size="50" value="<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>">
          <?php  if(isset($errEmail)) echo $errEmail; ?>
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                    </tr>          
                </table>
                <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
            </center>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exact error do you get? Please post the complete error, exactly as printed by php.

Comment: Might want to stick to the existing filters rather than relying on your own regex: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: it seems like you are missing a curly bracket `{` right after the if-clause condition and please escape your output on the value attribute of the input fields with [htmlspecialchars](http://us3.php.net/htmlspecialchars), otherwise you have a potential security issue and the user won't be happy if he enters special chars like <, > or "

Comment: @sled I think i fixed the curly bracket and I didn't know that the htmlspecialchars were a bad thing.  I'm Googling like a mad man and just found a whole bunch of examples that use that in their data validation.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is one that many programmers that are new to PHP run into. See, `$_POST` is an array that includes all parameters that have been submitted with the `POST` request the script was requested with. But what if there were none, or the script was requested using `GET`? You got it: it's empty.

In your case, `submit` doesn't seem to be present in the POST data. In that case you most likely want to just display the form, so the user can enter the data and submit the form (which will set that value). SO you have to check FIRST if "submit" is there.

Second: Your submit button is called "register", and it's value (which is not really necessary, but alright) is "Register". So if the form is submitted, the data that is sent is `register=Register&<other fields>`. Therefore you have to check for the presence  of "register", not "submit"

```
if (isset($_POST['register']) && $_POST['register']) {
    // evaluate
}
```

Comment: @Romel: If you already read that answer, please make sure you read it again, as I have added another paragraph and changed the code accordingly!

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip!  check to see if submit was there, then ... I'll apply that logic in my other forms.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you don't have check any var is set so you can see more  php error

i change more check, you can try

```
<html>
    <h4>
        <center>
            New User Registration
        </center>
    </h4>
    <body>
        <?php

      $errEmail    = "";
      $errUser     = "";
      $errPass     = "";

      //not too sure what this if statement suppose to be.
      if(isset($_POST["register"])){//1. no '{' 2. the post is not ckeck 'type', is 'name'

        // Email mask
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", $_POST["email"]) === 0)
          $errEmail = '<p class="errText">Email must comply with this mask: chars(.chars)@chars(.chars).chars(2-4)</p>';
        // User must be digits and letters
        if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}$/", $_POST["user"]) === 0)
          $errUser = '<p class="errText">User must be bigger that 5 chars and contain only digits, letters and underscore</p>';
        // Password must be strong
        //if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["pass"]) === 0)
        if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["pass"]) === 0)
          $errPass = '<p class="errText">Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit</p>';
      }    
  ?>
        <form method="post">
            <center>
                <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td ><input name="user" type="text" size="16" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["user"]))?$_POST["user"]:'';/*3.no check the var is set?*/ ?>">
          <?php  if(isset($errUser) and $errUser !='') echo $errUser; ?>
                        </td ><!--4. no '</td>'-->
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="pass" type="password" size="16" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["pass"]))?$_POST["pass"]:''; ?>">
          <?php  if(isset($errPass) and $errPass !='') echo $errPass; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr>
                                         <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="email" type="text" size="50" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["email"]))?$_POST["email"]:''; ?>">
          <?php  if(isset($errEmail) and $errEmail !='') echo $errEmail; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                    </tr>          
                </table>
                <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
            </center>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code up!  I just had foolish errors:(  Looks like you're beginning too! :)  Don't worry, your reputation will go up in no time :)